# Angular 5 Excel Office App Communication not happening from Dialog to Task Pane

Tags: angular, typescript, office-js

We are facing an issue while sending a message from Dialog to the Task pane in our Angular 5 Excel Single Page Application

We are able to open Dialog Window, but the callback event is not firing when we send a message from Dialog to the Task Pane.  Please find below is our code.

The code in the Task Pane:

```
openMainWindow() {
  this.message = "opening dialog";
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
    "https://localhost:3000/#/mainwindow",
    { height: 100, width: 100 },
    this.callBack
  );
}

callBack(result) {
  this.message = "opened dialog";
  this.dialog = result.value;
  this.dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, this.processMessage);
  this.message = this.dialog.toString();
}
```

The above callback event is not firing.

```
processMessage(arg) {
    this.message = "received a message from dialog";
    this.dialog.close();
    this.message = arg.message;
}
```

Code in the Dialog Window:

```
sendMessage() {
    this.message = "sending message to parent";
    Office.context.ui.messageParent("this is the message from child");
}
```

We have tested the same functionality using JQuery (multiple pages) and it is working fine, we are able to send and receive messages from Dialog.

If possible please help us or point us to someone on your team to solve this issue with Angular Excel App.

Comment: One side note, Stack Overflow is not a _Microsoft_ site, it is a community site (it's owned and operated by Stack Exchange Inc.).  While many companies have folks from product teams monitoring Stack (including Microsoft), the majority of answers here come from other community members. A prime example would be Jon Skeet, the top-ranked person on Stack. He mostly answers C# questions but not only is he _not_ on the C# team, he's an engineer at Google (and crazy smart but I digress). Something to keep in mind when you're posing questions. Particularly with Angular (a Google framework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very valuable page that covers some unique issues presented by Angular when building Office Web Add-ins: [Develop Office Add-ins with Angular](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2).

There is also an important note in the [Dialog API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#use-the-office-dialog-api-with-single-page-applications-and-client-side-routing) when it comes to SPA web apps:

> The dialog box is in a new window with its own execution context. If you pass a route, your base page and all its initialization and bootstrapping code run again in this new context, and any variables are set to their initial values in the dialog window. So this technique launches a second instance of your application in the dialog window. Code that changes variables in the dialog window does not change the task pane version of the same variables. Similarly, the dialog window has its own session storage, which is not accessible from code in the task pane.

I believe your trouble here has to do with `this` not pointing to the object you expect it too. You should be binding the callback to the proper `this` object:

```
openMainWindow() {
  this.message = "opening dialog";
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
    "https://localhost:3000/#/mainwindow",
    { height: 100, width: 100 },
    this.callBack.bind(this));
}
```